# Загрузка файла в память частями

Tags: delphi

Возможно ли в данном коде **подгружать и обрабатывать файл кусками (частями)**, к примеру по 100 000 строк (что бы не загружать память). Если возможно то подскажите (пытаюсь разобраться и очень интересно) ?

```
var
  sl: TStringList;
  i, j: integer;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    sl := TStringList.Create;
    Randomize;
    try
      sl.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
      for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do
      begin
        j := Random(sl.Count);
        if i <> j then
          sl.Exchange(i, j);
      end;
      sl.SaveToFile(ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + '\save.txt');
    finally
      FreeAndNil(sl);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Если в конце концов весь файл окажется в TStringList, то нет смысла грузить частями.

Comment: 100 000 строк это тьфу для современных компов. миллион строк - по 60 байт средняя длина какие-то 60 Мб всего. Браузеры влёт гигами отжирают. В 2 Гб будет 30-40 миллионов строк. Но вообще так неправильно софт проектировать. Используйте индексы и лучше разбивать по мелким файлам.

Answer (score 1):

1. Определить количество строк в файле `N`
2. Завести массив byte (если R укладывается в этот диапазон) флагов `run[N]`
3. Задать разумный размер выходной выборки строк `M`
4. Найти количество проходов `R = (N + M - 1) div M`
5. Записать в массив `run` M нулей, M единиц  и т.д. до `N mod M` значений `R-1`
6. Перемешать массив `run` с помощью тасования Фишера-Йетса
7. Сделать `R` проходов по файлу

   8. На i-м проходе записывать в выборку строки с такими номерами `k`, для которых `run[k] = i`
   9. Перемешать выборку с помощью тасования Фишера-Йетса
   10. Сбросить выборку в выходной файл